# Running SQL 2008 Express in '2005' mode

Tags: sql

currently i have SQL 2005 Express installed and wish to upgrade to 2008 express to gain the extra dbase limit (10gb)
my question is, if i run 2008 express in 2005 mode will this trunkate the dbase to the 2005 limit of 4gb or will it remain at the 2008 limit of 10gb?
Chris

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Express **still** has 4 GB limit - that limit has been raised to 10 GB only with the SQL Server 2008 **R2** Express edition.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the database compatibility level set to 90 ?

It will be 10GB AFAIK.

Comment: afaik, thankyou for your rapid feedback...that will help with an internal bottleneck, much appreciated